# CSS Media Device

Tags: html, css

I am working with 1st own website. And I want to create a responsible layout. 
This is my HTML code..

```
<link href="css/web_desktop.css" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:481px)" />

<link href="css/web_mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width:480px)" />
```

It works on my laptop, when I resize my browser. But somehow when I try to upload it and try to open it with my iPhone, it doesn't even work.
I've tried to put this code into my web_mobile.css file

> @media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
>   }

But still..

Do you guys have any suggestion ? And is it possible to create more than 2 css media query?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Put your media queries in your `.css` file as normal, and style how you would normally just in between the media queries.

[Here are a list of a lot of media queries you can use.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

You can just use 1 `.css` file then without having to use the `media` attribute when using `link` to call the `.css` file, as the queries will be within the `.css` file.

Comment: Why repeat the same queries multiple times?

Comment: @BeatAlex media is only for desktop? and media screen is for device such as ipad iphone? Thank you for the answer. Now i understand

Comment: @3rror404 Good spot, I didn't check it, just took all of the lines with '@media' in from bootstrap.css and copypasta'd. Updated now though with a better and more in depth list.

Comment: @AureliaAmelinda Updated with a better list with more queries on.